# Cluster assignment remapping

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have test classification datasets from UCI Machine Learning repository which are labelled.

I am stripping of the labels and using the data to benchmark a few clustering algorithm and then I am planning to use external validation methods. I will run the algorithm with different initial configurations, for say, 50 times and then take the mean value. For 50 iterations the algorithm labels the data points of one single cluster with different numbers. Because in each run the cluster labels can change, also because each iteration might have slightly different cluster assignments, how to somehow remap each of the clusters to one uniform numbering.

Primary idea is to remap by checking how many of the points in the class labels intersect the maximum in the actual labels and then making a remap based on that, but this can get incorrect remappings because when the classes will have more or less equal number of points, this will not work.

Another idea is to keep the labels while clustering, but make the clustering algorithm ignore it. This way all the cluster data will have the label tags. This is doable but I have already have a benchmarked cluster assignment data to be processed therefore I am trying to avoid modifying and re-benchmarking my implementation (which will take quite some time and cpu) of the cluster analysis algorithms and include the label tag to the vectors and then ignore it.

Is there any way that I can compute average accuracy from the cluster assignments I have right now?

**EDIT:**

The domain in which I am studying (metaheuristic clustering algorithms) I could not find a paper comparing these indexes. The paper which compares seems to be incorrect in their values. Can anyone point me to a paper where clustering results are compared using any of these indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you do when the *number* of clusters doesn't agree?

Do *not* try to map clusters.

Instead, use the proper external validation measures for clustering, which do not require a 1:1 correspondence of clusters. There are plenty, for details see Wikipedia.

Comment: I am using fixed number of clusters and none of them are empty. I will see the methods which does not require 1:1 correspondence. What you you say about the modified F-Measure here: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1641404

Comment: Try the *standard* measures like Rand, ARI, etc. first that don't need such a mapping. ;-)

Comment: Yes I should not need remapping. Read a few things and what I understood that contingency table based methods are possibly appropriate in my case. I am going to try out ARI. Currently implemented Purity and F measure as explained [here] (http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~zaki/www-new/uploads/Dmcourse/Main/chap18.pdf). 

The domain in which I am studying (metaheuristic clustering algorithms) I could not find a paper comparing these indexes. The paper which compares seems to be incorrect in their values. Can you point me to a paper where clustering results are compared using any of these indexes?

Comment: Plenty, just type ARI into scholar. E.g. "On the use of the adjusted rand index as a metric for evaluating supervised classification"... The ARI article "Comparing partitions, L Hubert, P Arabie, Journal of classification, 1985" has >3000 citations.